# Escape sequence jQuery for using variable inside quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, row, multiple-columns

I am trying to delete a column in table with the following.

```
var name = "1";
var name1= parseInt($name);
$('td:nth-child(name1)').hide();
```

This does not do anything. But if i hardcode it as

```
$('td:nth-child(1)').hide();
```

It deletes the column. Can anyone please suggest where i am going wrong?

Comment: concatenation is done with the `+` sign -> `$('td:nth-child('+name1+')').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the strings with the variables:

```
$('td:nth-child(' + name1 + ')').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not do [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).  So you need to concatenate your strings together like this:

```
var name = "1";
var name1= parseInt(name);  // removed $ before variable name
$('td:nth-child(' + name1 + ')').hide();
```

Or, without doing converting to int, which isn't really necessary:

```
var name = "1";
$('td:nth-child(' + name + ')').hide();
```

Comment: "Javascript does not do string interpolation." is not true, there are template literals that are supported in FF and Chrome and IE with Babel

Comment: @jdphenix - well, javascript **that has to work in the real world**, and not in ES6 transpilers, does currently not support template literals, but maybe in a few years or so.

Comment: To be clear (I realize re-reading my comment it's about as clear as mud), Firefox and Chrome support template literals out of the box for at least a year. Transpilers (which real world people use) would be needed for years old versions of those or Internet Explorer.